# Updating location of waypoint using QGIS/PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have two situations where I some times need to update the coordinates of a way point.  Firstly where the thing it is marking has been moved and secondly when I get a more accurate fix on the location.  (Some times the first the first report we get has a fix taken under heavy canopy, in a gully with a phone and these points can be many meters off)

Usually I end up with a layer with the new location in it and I want to update the entry in the master layer.

Since I am a programmer I can do this at the database (postgis) level but I am also looking for a simple method that will work for other, less technical, folk who maintain the data using QGIS.

The situation is complicated by the fact that the master waypoint table (which I want to update) is linked to other tables by foreign keys which means I can not simply delete the old entry in the table and replace it with the new data.  I.e. I *really* need to update the the location *in place*.

Comment: The Numerical Vertex Edit tool will allow a QGIS user to click the point that needs updating and enter the new LAT/LON value - that would be the manual method...

Comment: This does the trick in a simple straight forward way and is fine for small numbers of points.   I may look at writing a plugin which will automatically update points in one layer with coordinates from another layer for more extensive updates.  If you want to add this as an answer I am happy to accept it.

Comment: I have a script that does this now and I will rewrite it as a plugin when QGIS 3 is available.  Writing plugins on a Mac is problematic right now because of software version issues.  Be warned this is a work in progress and it needs to run under script runner plugin: https://github.com/rful011/qgisscripts/blob/master/update_layer.py